# Counting Rows where one row contains some data and other row another data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with following fields (few of them)

CustomerID, OrderNumber, TaxYear2013, TaxYear2012, TaxYear2011, FormType (and few other fields).

One customer may have requested different Form types (for the tax details). So data could be like this

```
Customer#     Order#       TaxYear2013    TaxYear2012    TaxYear2010    FormType
1111          100          True           True           True            4
1111          101          True           True           True            5
2222          102          True           False          True            4
3333          103          True           False          True            4
```

I need # of orders (Count(Order#)) with the following criteria.
If any of the TaxYear is true, count it as one. (that means, first row will have 3 + second row =3 + third row = 2 + fourth row =2). 
So currently, there are 10 Orders placed (counting one for each year).

That was simple, I counted that using this Query.

```
SELECT
(SELECT Count(OrderNumber) From tblOrder Where TaxYear2013 =1 )
+
(SELECT Count(OrderNumber) From tblOrder Where TaxYear2012 =1 )
+
(SELECT Count(OrderNumber) From tblOrder Where TaxYear2011 =1 )
+
(SELECT Count(OrderNumber) From tblOrder Where TaxYear2010 =1 )
as TotalYearsOrdered
```

However, I need to filter out records from one row and count from other row, based on the FormType.

If formType = 4 and also have formType=5 then count orders (based on above query) for FormType=4 only and ignore rows with FormType=5 for same customer. but if there is no row with FormType=4, then count it as it is.

So based on above data, we should we should ignore row# 2 as the same customer has FormType=5 and 4 (so we should only consider data from the row having FormType=4).

Is there any easy way to do that via SQL?

thanks
   Sameers

Comment: If I were you, thinking about the relentless way new years have a tendency to appear, I would normalise my data.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL:

```
select *
    , (y.TaxYear2013+y.TaxYear2012+y.TaxYear2010) as OrderCount
from (
    select *
        , (select top 1 TaxYear2013 from taxes t2 where t2.customerNo = z.customerNo order by formtype) as TaxYear2013
        , (select top 1 TaxYear2012 from taxes t2 where t2.customerNo = z.customerNo order by formtype) as TaxYear2012
        , (select top 1 TaxYear2010 from taxes t2 where t2.customerNo = z.customerNo order by formtype) as TaxYear2010
    from (
        select distinct customerNo 
        from taxes t
        ) z
    ) y
```

will produce this output:

```
customerNo  TaxYear2013 TaxYear2012 TaxYear2010 OrderCount
1111        1           1           1           3
2222        1           0           1           2
3333        1           0           1           2
```

Here is my test database setup:

```
use tryme
GO
drop table taxes
go
create table taxes (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key
    , customerNo int 
    , OrderNo       int
    , TaxYear2013   int
    , Taxyear2012   int
    , taxyear2010   int
    , formtype      int
)
GO
insert into taxes (customerNo, OrderNo, TaxYear2013, Taxyear2012, taxyear2010, formtype) values (1111,100,1,1,1,4)
insert into taxes (customerNo, OrderNo, TaxYear2013, Taxyear2012, taxyear2010, formtype) values (1111,101,1,1,1,5)
insert into taxes (customerNo, OrderNo, TaxYear2013, Taxyear2012, taxyear2010, formtype) values (2222,103,1,0,1,4)
insert into taxes (customerNo, OrderNo, TaxYear2013, Taxyear2012, taxyear2010, formtype) values (3333,104,1,0,1,4)
GO
select * from taxes
```

let me know if this does not solve your problem.

RosSQL.BlogSpot.com

Comment: This is good. However, there is one more thing I forgot to mention. There could be more form types. Like, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. We only need to consider if Formtype=4 AND formtype=5 available, then consider Formtype=4 only and ignore Formtype=5 (But still count other form types). In short, all form types are counted ( could be from 1 to 7) but if available 4 and 5, then ignore 5 and consider 4 only. Thank you.